# Creating EditText Dynamically in Android

Tags: android-edittext, dynamically-generated

I am working on a application where I have to create multiple
         `EditText` and Spinner dynamically. So I started looking 
        for the solution as I don't have permission to use **Invisible** 
        property in XML file. I searched a lot and got a very few examples 
        only on *stackoverflow* . I follow them and created this program.

```
       **MainActivity.java code** 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        RelativeLayout containerLayout;
        static int totalEditTexts = 0;
        Button button;
        Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    containerLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     totalEditTexts++;
     if (totalEditTexts > 100)
    return;
    EditText editText = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    containerLayout.addView(editText);
      editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.setMargins(23, 34, 0, 0);
     // RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()
       editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    //if you want to identify the created editTexts, set a tag, like below
     editText.setTag("EditText" + totalEditTexts);
                }
            });
```

}
}

When I am running this code, It is creating the EditText when the button got clicked. But only one time. I don't know what is happening after that. whether it is creating new EditText or it is overlapping the old one, otherwise it is not creating more than one EditText.

[image]

Can anyone explain me what I have to do now to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have Solved my Problem by simply replacing **RelativeLayout** with *LinearLayout*

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using RelativeLayout and adding stuff dynamically is that if you don't set the relative position of the view, it overlaps each other. So when you click and add new views, the new views are being added but they overlap each other. But adding a LinearLayout, the views are visible below one another as you can set the orientation to vertical.