# Creating Edit text using a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am creating an application that lets users to add editable text fields, and save data in it. Now my question is : How to add multiple Edit text boxes, whenever a button is pressed. Is there a way to do it, or any other alternative suggestion ?

Comment: Shaheen:what you have tried please show your effort.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056649/creating-edittext-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also you can just change the visibility of editText instead of creating them ! see this snippet :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/yourId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Then in java in your onClick method :

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
edt.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Its make your editText visible
Note : In this way you have better control on EditText and your design them in visibility and at the end get them hidden !

Comment: well , in that case, say i have 10 editable edit texts , so how do i make them visible one by one ?

Comment: the way is same ! you can save your edit texts id  in an `array` and set a counter like `i` then when you click on button you can set text the i`s edittext and change visibility of `i+1` or `i-1` textview as you want

Comment: bro, I have only tried arrays in C . I am a beginner in Java, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: this is a good tutorial : http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-java

Comment: google it ! you can find some good solution ! ( movafagh bashi ;) )